# Stock Python Program

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping

I have a problem with my code, it gives me this output every time. I have downloaded lxml, html.parser, and beautiful soup.
My code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= 'https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=DSS'

response= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')

print(soup)

price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'symbol-value-sub'})

print(price)
```

output:

```
[]
```

Comment: Welcome. Are you sure that server returned expected response?

Comment: I believe this page makes heavy use of javascript. In that case the beautifulsoup will not work. You will need to use something like Selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML tag is span, not div.

```
price = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'symbol-value-sub'})
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you click the tick on my answer so it's the accepted one?

Comment: how do you know when to put 'span' or 'div', because i am trying to continue my code, but it is giving me the same message. some of the code where i am getting the wrong output: soup = BeautifulSoup(responseJRJC.text,'html.parser')

print("Last JRJC")

last = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'pidExt-16436-last'})

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for span.

```
price = soup.find_all('span', {'class':'symbol-value-sub'})

for p in price:
    print(p.text) # 7.33
```